# Javascript dynamically invoke object method from string

Tags: javascript, oop, dynamic, methods, invoke

Can I dynamically call an object method having the method name as a string? I would imagine it like this:

```
var FooClass = function() {
    this.smile = function() {};
}

var method = "smile";
var foo = new FooClass();

// I want to run smile on the foo instance.
foo.{mysterious code}(); // being executed as foo.smile();
```

Answer (score 260, accepted):

if the name of the property is stored in a variable, use `[]`

```
foo[method]();
```

Comment: it's not working for me using a variable inside a function:const genericResolver = ( table, action , values ) => {
    return Auth.isAuthenticated()
      .then(() => {
        return eval(table).findAll()

Comment: If you want to execute a method from another method inside a class, use this['methodName']().

Comment: Getting this ugly error `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'FooClass'` anyone else ?

Answer (score 39):

Properties of objects can be accessed through the array notation:

```
var method = "smile";
foo[method](); // will execute the method "smile"
```

Answer (score 11):

When we call a function inside an object, we need provide the name of the function as a String.

```
var obj = {talk: function(){ console.log('Hi') }};

obj['talk'](); //prints "Hi"
obj[talk]()// Does not work
```

Comment: It's always helpful to provide some commentary with your code so it can be understood out of context.

Comment: Added some comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

method can be call with eval
    `eval("foo." + method + "()");`
might not be very good way.

Comment: Useful in my case where `foo` is `{ fields: [{ id: 1 }] }` and `method` is `fields[0]?.id`, but I had to remove `()` from your proposed answer

Answer (score 2):

I would like to leave an example here for this. For example; i want to call a dynamically check method while submitting the form.

```html
<form data-before-submit="MyObject.myMethod">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

```js
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
    
    var beforeSubmit = $(this).attr('data-before-submit');

    if( beforeSubmit ){

       params = beforeSubmit.split(".");
       objectName = params[0];
       methodName = params[1];

       result = window[objectName][methodName]($(this));

       if( result !== true ){
           e.preventDefault();
       }

    }

});
```

```js
var MyObject = {
    myMethod: function(form){
        console.log('worked');
        return true;
    }
};
```