# In javascript how to pass variable arguments without using arguments

Tags: javascript, variables, arguments

I have a function pool:

```
var func0 = function(a0){...}
var func1 = function(a0, a1){..}
var func2 = function(a0, a1, a3){...}
```

Now I got the function name and a arguments array:

```
var name = 'func1';
var params = [arg0, arg1];
```

Name is a dynamic string so I can't write like:

```
func1(arg0, arg1);
```

Is there any way can let the params passed into the function like reflection in java?

Note without using "arguments":

```
func(){ console.log(arguments[0]);}
```

@Felix Kling this is not a duplication, my question is how to pass variable parameters, and i know the way obj[name] but this doesn't help my question.

My question is how to convert params[arg0, arg1] into func(arg0, arg1), not func(params) and not func(){arguments[0]...argument[1]...}

Comment: Related: [Javascript dynamically invoke object method from string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9854995/218196)

Comment: this way:`function func1(a){alert(a)};window["func1"](2)`

Comment: @FelixKling this question is not a duplication. I know obj[name] but this doesn't help my question

Comment: It's not a duplicate of the question in the comments, but a duplicate of the question it is closed as duplicate of. Did you actually look at it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `eval` function, like this

```
eval(name+"("+params[0]+","+params[1]+")");
```

Comment: ah...maybe eval is not a good way...